# Is it possible to get list of OpenGL ES 2.0 methods which are vendor-specific?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Little backstory - I'm working on android application with OpenGL ES2.0 and some time ago I faced a problem with lines width, finally it turned out that `glLineWidth()` implementation is vendor specific, and the range of possible values is not guaranteed. For example for Adreno200 it is 1-18 and emulator I got 1-100.

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the list of such methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all such data from [glGet](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGet.xml) when running the program.

For example requesting `glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE,lineWidthRange);` would return the line width range.

The [OpenGL ES 2.0 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.withchanges.pdf) lists in its section 6.2 all the minimum requirements. From there we can see that line width range is guaranteed to be [1,1], everything else is implementation specific.

I am not aware of a list that would compare "all" implementations according to attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

The list of limits with vendor specific values is in the spec document. To find that:

1. Go to https://www.khronos.org/ (Khronos is the consortium responsible for the OpenGL ES standard).
2. Click on "OpenGL ES" in the tabs above the top pane on the page.
3. Click on "Specs & Headers" at the bottom of the pane. This will bring you to https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/.
4. Find the section "OpenGL ES 2.0 Specifications and Documentation", and click on "Full Specification". Or better yet, download the PDF file to have it handy for future use.

In this PDF file, look for section "6.2 State Tables", which starts on page 134. The information you're looking for is then in "Table 6.18 Implementation Dependent Values".

This table lists the name of each value, and the function to use for querying the value for your specific implementation. Also very useful, it lists the minimum value guaranteed to be supported by all implementations.

For your specific example, you will find a value `ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE`, which is the 6th entry in the table, with `GetFloatv` for the function name, `1,1` for the minimum supported value, and this for the description:

> Range (lo to hi) of aliased line widths

Based on this, you know that implementations can have a limit as low as 1 for the maximum line width (i.e. they do not support wide lines at all), and you can query the limit for the implementation you are using with:

```
GLfloat widthRange[2];
glGetFloatv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, widthRange);
```